# Resizing a cell in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to make some of my cells bigger in height. i tried using

```
CGRect rect = cell.frame;
NSLog(@"before height: %f",rect.size.height);
rect.size.height +=20;

cell.frame = rect;
NSLog(@"AFTER height: %f",cell.frame.size.height);
```

in

> cellForRowAtIndexPath

and

> willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
>   *)indexPath

The log shows that the values have changed but it doesnt show any change in the simulator.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Apple docs clearly explains what to do. [UITableView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

Every tableView has a delegate property.Set it to your viewController and implement above method. Its signature is

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So, based on **indexPath**, return whatever the height you desire.

If you want constant height for all rows, you can use `rowHeight` property of `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of UITableViewDelegate. Example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row == _pages.count - 1 ? 408 : 450;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make some cells bigger, you should implement the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (<SOMETHING>) {
        return height1;
    } else {
        return height2;
    }
}
```

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is for configuring the content of the cell that the tableView needs to display.

Note that `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` has performance implications if you have a really large table (1000+ entries), this method is called on every row when the table view displays.